# How to avoid setting fields to empty strings if value exists

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm working on my first node.js application and I need some help.

I use MongoDb as database.

In my application I have created a (sign up) method that reads user input such as email & password and sets the other fields like **first-name** & **last-name** to empty strings.

```
exports.postSignup = (request, response, next) => {
    const email = request.body.email;
    const password = request.body.password;
    const fonfirmPassword = request.body.confirmPassword;
    User.findOne({ email: email })
        .then(userDoc => {
            if (userDoc) {
                request.flash('error', 'Email already exists, please pick another!')
                return response.redirect('/auth/signup');
            }
            return bcrypt.hash(password, 12)
                .then(hashedPassword => {
                    const user = new User({
                        firstName: '',
                        lastName: '',
                        email: email,
                        photoUrl: '',
                        password: hashedPassword,
                        cart: { items: [] }
                    })
                    return user.save();
                })
                .then(result => {
                    response.redirect('/auth/login');
                    const signup = {
                        to: email,
                        from: 'support@company.com',
                        templateId: keys.SIGNUP_TEMPLATE_ID,
                        dynamic_template_data: {
                            subject: 'Signup succeeded successfully!',
                        },
                    };
                    sgMail.send(signup);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

The code above works fine... 
After a User has logged in to their account, that user is able to navigate to their profile page and set their **first-name** and **last-name** just as shown in the attached image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liiCX.png)

So I have created another method that allows a User to set their **first-name**, **last-name** and **photo-Url**

```
exports.postAddProfile = (request, response, next) => {
    const firstName = request.body.firstName;
    const lastName = request.body.lastName;
    const photoUrl = request.body.photoUrl;

    User.findOne({ userId: request.user.userId })
        .then(user => {
            user.firstName = firstName;
            user.lastName = lastName;
            user.photoUrl = photoUrl;
            return user.save();
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Added Profile Info');
            response.redirect('/');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
};
```

This code also works fine But the issue is if a User sets their **first-name**, **last-name** and **photo-Url** the first time like (Jonas, Jsk and https://photourl.com)
Then the second time if a User only changes the **first-name** then **last-name** and **photo-Url** are again set to empty strings.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty strings are falsies in JS, so just check if the `response` has a value that's not a empty string:

```
User.findOne({ userId: request.user.userId })
    .then(user => {
        user.firstName = firstName ? firstName : user.firstName;
        user.lastName = lastName ? lastName : user.lastName;
        user.photoUrl = photoUrl ? photoUrl : user.photoUrl;
        return user.save();
    })
```

Comment: Happy to be of service :)

Comment: I need help with another issue
It seems that `User.findOne({ userId: request.user.userId })` is not picking up the current logged in user. So if I have multiple singed up users in my database - the change is always affecting the first user in the database.

Comment: I think the problem is caused because there is no [`request.user`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_request_object.htm). Your solutions for this is to use `request.params.userId` if you want the user id to be visible in the url (the link for the route would be http://yourwebsite.com/user/:userId [the colon is mandatory]) or just use `request.body` again with the id in there. **OR:** you can implement browser sessions for your website, decent tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsOGmMuwhT4)

Comment: It took me some time but finaly fixed - Thanks again